# How to conditionally pass parameters into a func array

Tags: c#, expression, method-parameters

I have method that expects the following parameters:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        dbSet.Include(includeProperty);
    }
    return dbSet;
}
```

Here's how I pass in my params:

```
IQueryable<User> users = repo.GetAllIncluding(u => u.EmailNotices, u => u.EmailTemplatePlaceholders, u => u.Actions);
```

However, I need to be able to check certain conditions before I pass them in or not.

For example, if I have a variable `useEmailNotices = false`, then I don't want to pass in `EmailNotices` but if it's `true` then I do.  I need to do this for all three.  I know there's a long way to do this but I was hoping that there was a one line short way or a param builder function or something of that nature.

Comment: Repository... exposing IQueryable... Sigh...

Comment: @Phill What do you recommend?  I actually got that snippet of code from [Julie Lerman](http://pluralsight.com/training/Authors/Details/julie-lerman)

Comment: Exposing IQueryable<T> is a leaky abstraction, if you're going to expose that you may as well do away with the repository to begin with and just use your UoW directly.

Comment: Secondly you're got a TEntity which means you're using a base repository... http://www.philliphaydon.com/2014/01/if-youre-going-to-use-repositories-dont-have-generic-or-base-repositories/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about changing the signature of the method to

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includeProperties)
```

defining your conditional logic elsewhere

```
var args = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>();
if (useEmailNotices)
    args.Add(u => u.EmailNotices);
```

and then simply calling the method like

```
IQueryable<User> users = repo.GetAllIncluding(args);
```

Comment: @DavidKhaykin There's not exactly too much options here, is there? :)

Comment: Yep, only the List has to have the User entity, not the generic TEntity, I think.

Comment: Sounds like this is my only option.  i was hoping to not have to always have this line `var args = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>();` every time I use it but I just did an override so I can still use the easy way if there are no conditional params.

Comment: @RichC: you can obfuscate that into a method if you like but with needed conditions you'll have to declare a list and use more than one line to populate it.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Not really. If it's inside a generic class or method then it's valid to user `TEntity`.

Comment: oddly enough, this now prevents eager loading from occurring.  I set the conditions equal to true and I step through the options getting included to the dbset but they don't all return in the same query.  Each child entity makes a separate call.  When I run the same code the normal way (original code posted) it works as expected.

Comment: Interesting... I went back to using my original GetAllIncluding() method and just to an `IQueryable<User> users = repo.GetAllIncluding(args.ToArray());` and that fixed it.  Can you edit your answer to reflect this for future reference?

Comment: @RichC Interesting. I'm glad you figured it out on your own, I wouldn't be able to help you with this probably.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Params, use a `List<T>`, declared with the actual entity you wish to pass in:

```
var funcList = new List<Expression<Func<User, object>>>();

funcList.add(u => u.EmailTemplatePlaceholders);

if (useEmailNotices)
    funcList.add(u => u.EmailNotices);
```

And the method signature would now be:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> includeProperties)
{
    foreach( ... )
}
```